# How to modify apalike.bst to have a colon (:) instead of period (.) after "author (year)"?

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

I already modified `apalike.bst` to some of my needs, but I can't find this one -- which part do I have to change to have it include a colon after "author (year)" instead of a period `.`?

(I am using `bibtex` but not `biblatex`.)

Comment: I am using "author, year and colon followed by page number" like this( e.g. Brown,2001:38) what do you suggest for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apalike.bst` adds a period before outputting `\newblock`. So a way can be changing the function `output.year.check` into

```
FUNCTION {output.year.check}
{ year empty$
    { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$ }
    { write$
      " (" year * extra.label * ")\addcolonandeatperiod" *
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
}
```

along with

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\addcolonandeatperiod}{\@ifnextchar.{:\@gobble}\relax}
\makeatother
```

in your document preamble. There may be more efficient ways.