# Colon between address and institution

Tags: bibtex

I want to put a colon between my `address` and `institution` for `techreport` objects in `bibtex`. So it would be

> *Urban Mobility Report.* College Station, TX: Texas Transportation Institute.

I'm working from the `elsarticle-harv.bst` file. The I've edited the `techreport` output code to be:

```
FUNCTION {techreport}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  new.sentence
    address output.nonnull 
  institution "institution" output.check
  format.note output
  fin.entry
  write.url
}
```

This produces

> *Urban Mobility Report.* College Station, TX, Texas A&M University Transportation Institute.

which is fine but not ideal. I've tried to fix this by writing the following code

```
FUNCTION {output.address.check}
{ address empty$
    { "empty address in " cite$ * warning$ }
    { write$
        address * "\addcolonandeatcomma" *
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
}
```

and adding the relevant code to my preamble (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82472/12874) for details) and changing the `techreport` line to read `address output.address.check` Confusingly, this gives

> College Station, TX *Urban Mobility Report.* College Station, TX: Texas A&M University Transportation Institute.

What's up with this?